# Stop USB mobile broadband automatically mounting as drive

Tags: ubuntu, mount, automounting, mobile

**UPDATE 3:**

This is what I get from `lsusb`:

```
oshirowanen@laptop:~$ sudo lsusb
[sudo] password for oshirowanen: 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 19d2:0031 ONDA Communication S.p.A. ZTE MF636
```

As I have tried the following and it did not work:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ATTR{idVentor}=="ZTE MF636", ATTR{idProduct}=="19d2:0031",ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}:="1"
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
OS = Ubuntu 10.04.2
USB Stick = ZTE MF112
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I've looked at the documentation for usb_modeswitch, but find it to complex to understand.  Can someone please point me to a step by step guide on how to use it and setup my usb drive?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Is it possible to stop my usb mobile broadband stick from automatically mounting as a drive, yet continue to mount all other usb devices (camera, usb memory stick, usb camera etc) as normal, i.e. usb memory stick, usb harddrive stick should mount as normal usb drives as they currently do, web cam should mount as a cam as it does etc etc?

Basically, when I plug in the mobile broadband usb stick, it automatically mounts as a usb drive, and I have to unmount it.  It then automatically gets detected as a mobile broadband device.

So if it is possible to stop just the mobile broadband usb stick from mounting as a drive, it should automatically get detected as a mobile broadband device.

Can this be done?  I am using Ubuntu
10.04.

Comment: Which stick do you have? Which version of ubuntu do you use? Maybe AU would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Added details to update 2 in original question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with udev rules. I don't have ubuntu, but you can try this. Create a file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide.rules` with the following in it:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ATTR{idVentor}=="<VENDID>", ATTR{idProduct}=="<DRIVECODE>",ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}:="1"
```

Where you have to substitute your usb storage device's vendor and product ID for the  and  fields. Find that out with the `lsusb` command.

Comment: Please see update 3.  I don't know which part of that info is the vendor string which which part is the product id.

Comment: @oshiro Replace the "<VENDID>" with "19d2", and "<DRIVECODE>" with "0031". But that might not still work since that looks like the modem. Some devices have multiple endpoints and we'll have to specify the particular endpoint for the storage function.

Comment: So wouldn't this be better done with usb_modeswitch?

Comment: If his is the kind of device that does that. It's worth a try. I haven't used that product myself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tweak your device with command:

> usb_modeswitch

http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch